# Автоматизация сайта,как лучше? Python

Tags: python-3.x

Мне нужно автоматизировать авторизацию на сайте и последующую с ним работой.Я в этой сфере совсем новичок, и нагуглил такую вещь как selenium web driver,но столкнулся с тем что, банально не могу авторизоваться,выходит капча которую невозможно решить.Так вот есть ли другие возможности сделать это?

Comment: Всё зависит от сайта. Возможно там есть апи для которого можно получить токен и работать с ним напрямую. Если такого нет, либо вводить капчу вручную, либо использовать платные сервисы для её решения, rucaptcha например.

Comment: @ПавелДурманов Смотрите вот параметры для пост запроса например:`recaptcha 03AF6jDqUHM9w-Elo-lUYzbYiRH7nVw0IIgh5bj2QYNH4WFclGEOPiyhLBa2BVItFdZSjQ4lT-
otv:1
recaptchaLevel:1
login:login
pass:pass`  откуда мне взять вот этот код рекапчи?

Comment: Это я полагаю код уже решенной капчи

Comment: @ПавелДурманов точно,а как мне вытащить ее для ручного решения,я так понимаю в других файлах которые передаются через get?

Comment: @ПавелДурманов просто я ее не решаю при авторизации,она сама как то без интерфейса

Comment: Инспектируйте код страницы, в капче есть токен который можно передать сервисам решения капчи и получить результат, тот что вы скинули выше